# How can I change the way GHC compiler error messages are printed out?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

I am not fully satisfied with the format of GHC error messages. How can I make a custom print function?

Comment: What does GHC comiler-error messages have to do with parsec...?

Comment: This is a statement of what you want to do, not a question.  Have you tried using parsec to parse GHC error messages or are you asking someone else to tell you how to do it?

Comment: @bheklilr The title is the question - "How can I change the format of GHC compiler-error messages?". I am asking someone else to tell me how to do it, obviously.

Comment: @xged this is clearly a full project, we aren't going to do it for you. It seems like you have a plan (using parsec), so go do it. Why would you want to change the format of GHC compiler error messages? It has by far the best error messages of any compiler I've used.

Comment: @xged then you aren't going to get much help other than read a parsed tutorial. Stackoverflow is not the place to request code to be written, it's a place to get help stuck writing code. You have to have an attempt first before you can be stuck on it.

Comment: @bheklilr I updated the question, hope that will clear things up.

Comment: @xged While it improves on your intent, it still does not follow the [how to ask guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll have to write your own parser for the error messages that converts the text to a custom data type. From there you can print them however you want, but without knowing what about the error messages you don't like and how you want to improve them to there really isn't much else I can tell you. You've come here with a problem statement, not with a specific roadblock in existing code and not many people want to spend their day solving your problems for you.

Comment: @alternative That does not mean messages cannot be improved upon.

Comment: @xged Yes, it does. Anything that you can do by parsing the error messages is limited to the amount of information in the error message. You can't get any better, you can only reformat it...

Comment: @bheklilr "From there you can print them however you want" - **I do not know how to do it**. That is my question. Forget the parser. Say I want to delete first line of an error message - HOW?

Comment: @xged Don't print it?

Comment: I'm often frustrated with the wall of text that sometimes tells you that you forgot a comma. It's probably the #1 worst thing about the development experience. However, I understand that this is a problem for the phds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify GHC? well, it's open-source so you can change it however you wish and recompile but that would probably be a gigantic overkill.

If I really really wanted to, I'd make a program that calls GHC with the arguments it receives, read back the output, process it, then print it.

You can do it with [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html).[`readProcessWithExitCode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcessWithExitCode), specifically.
You might be tempted to use [`readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess) for its easier API, but it will only read from `stdout` and you're almost certainly want `stderr` too.
Plus the exit-code in the former function could be very helpful too: you could know if compilation succeeded or not without even parsing, but by just seeing if the exit code = 0.